# 404 Not Found Put service in postman and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, postman

I have created put API in spring boot Application, Put what is happening that it's returning 404 not found, This is my **Controller** :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerServiceImpl customerService;
    @PutMapping("/customer/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id, @RequestBody CustomerDTO customer) {
        try{
            Customer newCustomer = customerService.updateCustomer(customer);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(newCustomer, HttpStatus.OK);

        }catch (Exception exception){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my **service** :

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Customer updateCustomer(CustomerDTO customer) {
        if (cutomerRepository.findById(customer.getId()) != null) {
            Customer persistenceCustomer = cutomerRepository.findById(customer.getId()).get();
            if (customer.getEmail() != null) {
                persistenceCustomer.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
                ;
            }
            if (customer.getMobileNumber() != null) {
                persistenceCustomer.setMobileNumber(customer.getMobileNumber());
            }
            if (customer.getInvoices().size() > 0) {
                persistenceCustomer.setInvoices(customer.getInvoices());
            }

            return cutomerRepository.save(persistenceCustomer);
        }
```

The api in postman :
[image]

and there's data in database:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any "context-path" somewhere in the .properties file? I think you're not reaching out to the controller, so better to check the Start-up log - for the context-path, port and etc. From the info you provided, I can't see any issue

Comment: Is your Controller class in same package as class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`? If not add this on your main class `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {com.pathToYourControllerPackage})` and try ! Also just for your information, do work on REST API naming conventions

Comment: @Harsh but what are code conventions for REST API's please ?

Comment: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/  & https://nordicapis.com/10-best-practices-for-naming-api-endpoints/ Check these out, did above work ?

Comment: Also, log something in your Exception handling, or add custom text to the response, so you can tell if it's your 404 being returned or something from Spring.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your code, everything looks ok up to the point of where you ask for the size of the `invoices` collection in the `updateCustomer` method of the service:

```
if (customer.getInvoices().size() > 0) {
    persistenceCustomer.setInvoices(customer.getInvoices());
}
```

In your Postman screenshot there are no invoices being passed, so, even if the `CustomerDTO` has a property (which I assume it does) to hold a List (or any suitable collection) for the invoices, if no invoices information is being received in the body the request, that field will be likely be null, which will trigger the exception you are catching once you try to return the size of the (null) `invoices` property. So I am betting on that you are getting a nullPointerException instead of a real `NOT_FOUND`.

So, one possible solution would be to check whether the `invoices` property of `customer` is null before attempting to get the collection size.

Hope this helps.